# how to pass or share open stream reference in a multithreaded program?

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, io, telnet

*(Note, an SSH API won't work because it's for a MUD client, and not many MUD's support SSH, they still use telnet.  Also, for the duration of the program execution, no streams are closed.  If a stream closes that, effectively, ends that run of the program.)*

When I came at this [previously](https://github.com/THUFIR/rainmaker/blob/master/src/telnet/InputOutput.java), I had a different organization which gave each thread a reference to the connection.  However, that was using Apache [TelnetClient](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/telnet/TelnetClient.html) (which comes with its own set of pros and cons), whereas this is with just plain sockets.

Also, I'm trying to take advantage of the `try with resources` statement for [multithreaded socket communication](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/socket-140484.html#multi).  It seems that this new `try` might not allow some organization which the previous `try` allowed?  At least, I'm so far unable to organize the variables and threads so that each thread has a reference to the various streams involved.

The threads should **not** block each other.  For example, output from the remote connection should print to the console regardless of what is being typed.  Similarly, any user input should get sent to the remote connection posthaste.  (Perhaps input and output will be split screen in a later version.)

Perhaps a parent thread to pass messages (`String` objects) between them?

The remote thread works fine, and the local thread works fine, but there's no way, currently, to send messages from the local thread to the remote thread:

```
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/MudSocketClient$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/MudSocketClient$ java -jar dist/MudSocketClient.jar 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*               Welcome to THE WEATHER UNDERGROUND telnet service!            *
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*                                                                            *
*   National Weather Service information provided by Alden Electronics, Inc. *
*    and updated each minute as reports come in over our data feed.          *
*                                                                            *
*   **Note: If you cannot get past this opening screen, you must use a       *
*   different version of the "telnet" program--some of the ones for IBM      *
*   compatible PC's have a bug that prevents proper connection.              *
*                                                                            *
*           comments: jmasters@wunderground.com                              *
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Press Return to continue:


you entered ""

hmm


you entered "hmm"

^Cthufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/MudSocketClient$ 
thufir@dur:~/NetBeansProjects/MudSocketClient$
```

The text never makes it to the remote connection.  The code:

```
public class Telnet {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        final String host = "rainmaker.wunderground.com";
        final int port = 3000;

        Thread local = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                Scanner scanner;
                String line;
                while (true) {
                    scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                    line = scanner.nextLine();
                    out.println("\n\nyou entered\t\"" + line + "\"\n");
                }
            }
        };
        local.start();
        Thread remote = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                int byteOfData;
                try (Socket socket = new Socket(host, port);
                        InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
                        OutputStream ouputStream = socket.getOutputStream();
                        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                        final BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
                    while ((byteOfData = inputStream.read()) != -1) {
                        out.print((char) byteOfData);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    out.println(e);
                }
            }
        };

        remote.start();
    }
}
```

Which is a sort of poor-man's Telnet.

Comment: Your use of an opening out-of-context paragraph and a link to another question make this question difficult to read as a stand-alone question. Might be worth an edit? It's not very clear what your question actually is.

Comment: Heh, fair enough.  I spent a while coming up with that one!  I'll take a look at it, certainly.

Comment: You have 2 threads both trying to read from System.in. System.in is effectively a Stream, the content can only be read out of it 1 time. When the first thread (local) reads it out, it is no longer available for the second thread (remote) to read.

Answer (score 1):

Open a socket in main thread and make it global than pass that socket to a new thread.
This is how you can do this.

```
//Declare Socket socket.
main ()
{
      //open socket
      while(true)
      {
             //read a connection 
             //Creat a thread and Pass newly socket to thread.
      }
}
run()
{ 
       //Do your things here.
}
```